# Access pages with forms authentication from c#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, security

I'm trying to implement the code from this page: http://www.ksingla.net/2006/08/sample_forms_authentication_test_in_csharp/

It's working as expected all the way until the last response

```
        String cookie = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(...);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

That gives me a timeout :(

And I do have content in the cookie variable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `var responseContent = response.ReadToEnd()`

That should get you the details of your response wich u can read out

Comment: HttpWebResponse don't have a ReadToEnd method.

And the timeout is on the request.GetResponse() method

Comment: `System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
           var responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()` Works fine for me though

Comment: Sure - but I get a timeout error on your first line (and my last)

Comment: {"The operation has timed out"} from System.Net.WebExceptions

Comment: Is there a way to see the traffic with the external site like the developer in Chrome?

Comment: Have tried with a cookie container instead, but that didn't help anything

   request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   Cookie thecookie = new Cookie("xxx", cookie.Substring(10,cookie.Length-28),"/","xxxx");
   request.CookieContainer.Add(thecookie);

Comment: Fiddler monitors HTPP traffic

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have solved this but I had the same problem and solved it by closing the response with response.Close() before each new request was sent!